# How to get user info in a react app which uses auth0 for authentication

Tags: javascript, reactjs, auth0, userinfo

I was trying to get user info from login using twitter in auth0. auth0 provides **userInfo api** for getting users details, but it is just returning an object with a key sub (like this - `{"sub":"twitter|XXXXXXXXX"}` ). As per the [documentation](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/react/02-user-profile) provided, we should get the name, picture, nickname etc, in my case only one **sub** is returning. I wanted to know how the details of user can be fetched in auth0.

edit - providing the configs used.

```
auth0 = new auth0.WebAuth({
        domain: AUTH_CONFIG.domain,
        clientID: AUTH_CONFIG.clientId,
        redirectUri: AUTH_CONFIG.callbackUrl,
        audience: `https://${AUTH_CONFIG.domain}/userinfo`,
        responseType: 'token id_token',
        scope: 'openid'
    });
```

Comment: the `sub` you are seeing is the user_id property - have you taken a look at the user-profile endpoint (here: https://auth0.com/docs/api/authentication#user-profile) ? did you provide `openid` for the scope of the access token? are you apply to share the code where you are making the call?

Comment: Yes, the scope was the point. I have given the `scope` as **'openid'**. But when I just changed `scope` as **'openid profile'**, it worked. Thanks!

Comment: woo great! :) glad it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question does not offer any details on how you are making the authentication request with Twitter social connection. At a minimum, suggest that you try adding `scope: openid profile email` to your authentication request.  That will ensure the `id_token` returned contains all OIDC conformant user profile attributes (claims).

Please see the [documentation](https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/tutorials/adoption/scope-custom-claims) for details.

If you visit the [auth0 dashboard social connections](https://manage.auth0.com/#/connections/social) you can see what twitter returns to Auth0. With OIDC conformance enabled you can expect to see at least basic info like `sub` (user id), `name`, and `picture`. Screenshot below - please make sure you did tick the checkbox for Basic Profile user consent.

[image]

Comment: `auth0 = new auth0.WebAuth({
        domain: AUTH_CONFIG.domain,
        clientID: AUTH_CONFIG.clientId,
        redirectUri: AUTH_CONFIG.callbackUrl,
        audience: `https://${AUTH_CONFIG.domain}/userinfo`,
        responseType: 'token id_token',
        scope: 'openid'
    });` this was the config. As @kimcodes mentioned about scope, I found that the problem is in the scope and modified as **openid profile** it worked.

Comment: @manjs - please can you mark this answer correct - have highlighted the need to add `openid profile email` - it would help others visiting this question to have trust in the answer provided - disclaimer, i also work at Auth0 ;)